# Merge/Append pandas dataframes but update overlapping rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have two (or more) dataframes that I want to append under each other (or outer merge, in a way). How do I make sure that I can append the two dataframes, but at the same time, if an index is the same, I want to update the value of the variable with the second (dfB) dataframe.
As an illustration:

```
dfA = 
Index Var1
A     5 
B     6
C     7

dfB = 
Index Var1
A     6
D     8
E     10
```

Desired output should look like

```
output = 
Index Var1
A     6
B     6
C     7
D     8
E     10
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, considering the update, you can use `pd.concat()` with the argument `ignore_index=True` and `drop_duplicates(['index'])`

```
output = pd.concat([dfA,dfB],ignore_index=True)drop_duplicates(['index'],keep='last')
```

Example:

```
A = {'Index':['A','B','C'],'Var1':[5,6,7]}
B = {'Index':['A','D','E'],'Var1':[6,7,8]}
dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)
output = pd.concat([dfA,dfB],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(['Index'],keep='last')
print(output)

  Index  Var1
1     B     6
2     C     7
3     A     6
4     D     7
5     E     8
```

After this you can use `set_index()` or `sort_values()` if you want to sort your dataframe in alphabetical order given the column `Index`

Answer (score 1):

You can also `merge` and `fillna`:

```
final = (df1.merge(df2,on='Index',how='outer',suffixes=('_x',''))
       .assign(Var1 = lambda x: x['Var1'].fillna(x['Var1_x']))[df1.columns])
```

---

```
  Index  Var1
0     A   6.0
1     B   6.0
2     C   7.0
3     D   8.0
4     E  10.0
```